# Backup all github repo to bitbucket

Tags: github, gitlab, bitbucket, github-api, bitbucket-api

similar question: [Auto mirror all GitHub repository to gitlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66280977/auto-mirror-all-github-repository-to-gitlab)

GitLab supports a pull mirror, which makes backup from github to gitlab much easier.

does bitbucket support mirror also?
if not, is "using a server to push changes" the only way to backup all repo from github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does bitbucket support mirror also

No pull mirror that I know of, only [smart mirror](http://does%20bitbucket%20support%20mirror%20also) (to mirror remote repositories locally)

> if not, is "using a server to push changes" the only way to backup all repo from github?

Yes, except it would be the GitHub servers, not your own.
You could use [`actions/mirroring-repository`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/mirroring-repository):

> A GitHub Action for mirroring a repository to another repository on GitHub, GitLab, BitBucket, AWS CodeCommit, etc.
>
> This will copy all commits, branches and tags.

Example, from [`pixta-dev/repository-mirroring-action` issue 3](https://github.com/pixta-dev/repository-mirroring-action/issues/3)

```yaml
# Deploy to BitBucket repos

name: Deploy to BitBucket Wordpress Repositories


# You may pin to the exact commit or the version.
# uses: pixta-dev/repository-mirroring-action@02f1627ade9e6b3b69e6a6d4fe8bc997474f48d1
# uses: pixta-dev/repository-mirroring-action@v1
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  deploy_to_test_repo:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - uses: pixta-dev/repository-mirroring-action@v1
        with:
          target_repo_url:
            git@bitbucket.org:username/reponame.git
          ssh_private_key:
            ${{ secrets.BITBUCKET_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
```

Except you would need to [use an access key](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/add-access-keys/).

Comment: so I need to set up a Github action for EACH repo? that's very time-consuming.......

Comment: @LukAron It is one file to add, which can be done by script, using  standard git commands.

Comment: what script do you mean? could u give a link to ref

Comment: @LukAron You can list your repositories: https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_list. For each oe, you can add a `.github/workflows/mirror.yml` file (like there are other workflows in https://github.com/cli/cli/tree/trunk/.github/workflows for instance). With said `mirror.yml` one modelled after the answer above.

Comment: do u know this also?  since I want everything auto. 
 Need auto way for repo creation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68875135/bitbucket-repository-creations-by-api